# Persistent Data and Primitive Datatypes Ios Programming

Tags: ios, types, persistent, primitive-types

I am writing an app for the iPhone that needs to store integers so that when the user opens the app, it will be able to retrieve the integers stored from the last session and when the program has ended, it will store the integers. The problem that I am having is that there is a problem with storing primitive data types such as integers.

Comment: How are you trying to store them?

Comment: Well since I will only need to save five or six integers, would it be better to use fopen()?

Comment: For that few, `NSUserDevaults` is dead simple.

Comment: I forgot to add that none of the integers are associated with any of the objects on the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small amounts of data you can use NSUserDefaults which has methods to save primitive types such as:

```
- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
- (void)setFloat:(float)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
- (NSInteger)integerForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
- (float)floatForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

Otherwise convert them to `NSNumber` types and save as objects, perhaps in a plist.

```
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithInt:(int)value
+ (NSNumber *)numberWithFloat:(float)value
- (int)intValue
- (float)floatValue
```

If you have a substantial amount of data consider CoreData.

Example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"myStringValue" forKey:@"myStringKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:42 forKey:@"myIntegerKey"];

NSString *myRetreivedString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"myStringKey"];
NSInteger myRetreivedInteger = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myIntegerKey"];

NSLog(@"myRetreivedString: '%@'", myRetreivedString);
NSLog(@"myRetreivedInteger: %d", myRetreivedInteger);
```

NSLog output:

```
myRetreivedString: 'myStringValue'
myRetreivedInteger: 42
```